# How To Run Program As A Different User

Tags: 10.10, gedit, username

I'm trying to launch programs as a different user than what I'm logged in as. For testing I've been using gedit. When I type `sudo -u app_restricted gedit`, I get an error, `app_restricted` being the username of the other user account. The user account in question has limited permissions.

Error message:

```
No protocol specified
(gedit:2139): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
```

System Details:

> Ubuntu 10.10 - Desktop X86-64 with kernel 3.9 (from raring)

**PS:** I've also tried `su -u`, and `gksu -u` but they don't work either.

Comment: Have you tried logging in to the other account to ensure that it is all set up correctly &/or running a command line only task using that account?

Comment: This question is about an [end of life Ubuntu release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). These are no longer supported and are therefore off-topic here.

Comment: When I login to the other user account "app_restricted" it works fine, I can run gedit, or whatever else I want no problems.

Comment: yes my release is outdated, but I'm sure the commands to do this will be exactly the same on 13.04, which I also have installed.

Comment: Yes, the commands will be exactly the same but outcome may be different. And if you use kernel from another release I'm sure that you will have a lot of another problems.

Comment: If I type: "sudo -u app_restricted -l gedit" I don't get the error, I get "/usr/bin/gedit" and nothing happens. I've tried adding "app_restricted" to the list of sudoers, and it makes no difference, though I'm not sure I did it correctly, I typed "app_restricted ALL=(ALL) ALL". Plus I would prefer this user not be able to use sudo.

Comment: @Alaa: on one hand yes, on the other, it likely has nothing to do with the Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, as far as I can tell, that another user is not allowed to access your X window system. Otherwise any user on the system would be able to open popup-windows on your desktop ad libitem. You will likely have to solve the problem by providing an appropriate X authorization via XAUTHORITY environmental variable.

When you run `sudo -u app_restricted -l /usr/bin/gedit` it only means that you list the programs that the user is allowed to run. Since you tell what the program you are asking about, it only lists that one. Yes, user app_restricted is allowed to run the program... in this users X session, but not in *your* X session.

Comment: One can use the xhost command to allow remote access to the display. This also works for local users. To enable all connections (warning: use for testing only, for real use, restrict access!) run "xhost +"

Comment: @soulsource yes, you are absolutely right.